# How best to index for max values in data frame?

Tags: r

Here dataset in use is genotype from the cran package,MASS.

```
> names(genotype)
[1] "Litter" "Mother" "Wt"

> str(genotype)
'data.frame':   61 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Litter: Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","I","J": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Mother: Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","I","J": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ Wt    : num  61.5 68.2 64 65 59.7 55 42 60.2 52.5 61.8 ...
```

This was the given question from a tutorial:
Exercise 6.7. Find the heaviest rats born to each mother in the genotype() data.

tapply, whence split by factor genotype$Mother gives:

```
> tapply(genotype$Wt, genotype$Mother, max)
   A    B    I    J 
68.2 69.8 61.8 61.0
```

Also:

```
> out <- tapply(genotype$Wt, genotype[,1:2],max)
> out
      Mother
Litter    A    B    I    J
     A 68.2 60.2 61.8 61.0
     B 60.3 64.7 59.0 51.3
     I 68.0 69.8 61.3 54.5
     J 59.0 59.5 61.4 54.0
```

First tapply gives the heaviest rats from each mother , and second (out) gives a table that allows me identify which type of litter of each mother was heaviest.  Is there another way to match which Litter is has the most weight for each mother, for instance if the 2 dim table is real large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From stats:

```
aggregate(. ~ Mother, data = genotype, max)
```

or

```
aggregate(Wt ~ Mother, data = genotype, max)
```

Comment: This will also give the `max` values of the `factor` variable 'Litter'.  Based on the code showed by the OP, I am not sure how this becomes the expected output.

Answer (score 3):

We could use `data.table`. We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(genotype)`).  Create the index using `which.max` and subset the rows of the dataset grouped by the 'Mother'.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(genotype)[, .SD[which.max(Wt)], by = Mother]
#   Mother Litter   Wt
#1:      A      A 68.2
#2:      B      I 69.8
#3:      I      A 61.8
#4:      J      A 61.0
```

If we are only interested in the `max` of 'Wt' by 'Mother'

```
setDT(genotype)[, list(Wt=max(Wt)), by = Mother]
#   Mother   Wt
#1:      A 68.2
#2:      B 69.8
#3:      I 61.8
#4:      J 61.0
```

Based on the last `tapply` code showed by the OP, if we need similar output, we can use `dcast` from the devel version of 'data.table'

```
dcast(setDT(genotype), Litter ~ Mother, value.var='Wt', max)
#   Litter    A    B    I    J
#1:      A 68.2 60.2 61.8 61.0
#2:      B 60.3 64.7 59.0 51.3
#3:      I 68.0 69.8 61.3 54.5
#4:      J 59.0 59.5 61.4 54.0
```

#### data

```
library(MASS)
data(genotype)
```